# Invalid constantexpr bitcast

Tags: ocaml, llvm

I'm trying to get the i8 pointer to a constant struct using bitcast, but get this error:

```
llvm_test: Constants.cpp:1811: static llvm::Constant*
llvm::ConstantExpr::getBitCast(llvm::Constant*, llvm::Type*, bool): 
Assertion `CastInst::castIsValid(Instruction::BitCast, C, DstTy) && 
"Invalid constantexpr bitcast!"' failed.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the code is very basic (in OCaml):

```
let const = const_struct llctx [|const_int i32_t 1;|] in
let ptr = const_bitcast const i8_ptr_t in  <--- Explodes here
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

const_struct returns {i32} not {i32}*. You have to put it into a global to turn it into a pointer.